# Flat UI terminal, works on OSX not on Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, theme

I want to use this terminal theme on Linux Mint 18 Sarah Cinnamon 64-bit.

https://github.com/ahmetsulek/flat-terminal

When you open the flat.terminal on OSX it opens up a bash terminal with that theme. In Linux it opens in Firefox showing the code. Is there a way to make this work on Linux?

Comment: @Christopher I tried to edit some of that info you are requesting into the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: no

long: you could *translate* the file, but it happens to work as described on OSX because (a) the file-suffix tells OSX what it is and (b) the file-contents are an exported theme for OSX `Terminal`.  For reference, this is the beginning of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ANSIBlackColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NPECYw
    LjE4MDM5MjE2MSAwLjIzOTIxNTcwMTggMC4zMTc2NDcwNjk3ABACgALSEBESE1okY2xh
    c3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3RfEA9OU0tleWVkQXJjaGl2
    ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSE5bYouNj5SfqLCzvM7R1gAAAAAAAAEBAAAAAAAA
    ABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADY
```

For any other system, the theme would not work (without preparation) because the settings mean something only to the program(s) which read it and know what it is.

Comment: I would assume translating would not be an easy task? Appreciate the explanation and answer :)

Comment: Probably - the long base64 string appears to be an array of the color values.  There don't appear to be (m)any tools available for translating it.  On the other side, the various "terminal" settings configurations are poorly documented.

Answer (score 1):

I made a .json file. Put this into your terminal config. ;)

https://gist.github.com/kylerschin/c838bd42127270af5aab18d1eefc0b0b

Comment: Share your method - give a man a fish and he eats for a day, teach him to fish and he never hungers and all that

Comment: @cat My guess would be that it's translated from the iterm theme in the github repository, which is a great deal more human-readable than the terminal.app theme.

Comment: @Random832 well, of course, i'm mostly requesting the code or tools to do so, because i doubt it was done manually